# How to make Bluetooth app in Flutter and send commands to connected Devices?

Tags: flutter

I have to make an flutter app which pairing the devices and connects devices with the Bluetooth with the password and send the command to Connected devices.

Please Can anyone help me out.
and please if possible please refer a example.

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking for a whole project. Be specific

Comment: No, If is there any example available on any website please refer. or if you have any idea about it so please suggest me.

Comment: Try using any of this https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter+bluetooth+  or https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter+blue   which may help